# Android Fragment onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

my fragment transition is happened very weirdly. I am trying to open up new fragment upon back button is pressed:

```
//removed code
```

Then, when I am at home fragment, without me back press again, it will close the apps:

```
// removed code
```

I don't understand why switching from one fragment to another shares the same onKey? As in isn't it supposed to be behave like this: I back press in fragment 2, open up home fragment, inside home fragment I back press again, then it closes the apps.

Currently it's working like this: fragment 2 back press, open up home fragment, without me touching any thing, it goes into the onKey in home fragment.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Remove finish call "getActivity().finish();" then try...

```
v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
                getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

If not then try another solution...Add this method in your parent activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 FragmentManager fragmentmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();

 if(fragmentmanager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
         fragmentmanager.popBackStack();
    } else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope it still closes on its own when I call up home fragment from fragment 2. It shows up for a super duper brief moment then closes on its own.

Comment: okay, why you are using back task here.. do in parent activity

Comment: Because I wanted to set it to go back to home fragment before going back again to the parent activity

Comment: It tells me method does not override from its superclass. My home fragment is extending Fragment though

Comment: Nope it does not work that way. Because I got different section which serve different purpose, so basically in each section when I back press, I wanted to open up the home fragment instead of slowly pop them out one by one. For instance, I go from Setting to Expense to Profile, when I back press in Profile, I wanted to go back to Home instead of Profile -> Expense -> Setting -> Home

Comment: I don't understand why from fragment 2 back press open up home fragment, without me pressing back again, it goes into the onKey immediately